# NumberFormatException when parsing String to Int

Tags: java, numberformatexception, parseint

I am writing code to get the coefficients and exponents of a user entered polynomial. For an example, I am entering "-3x^4+2x^3+1x^2-1x^1+8x^0" into the console. I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at polynomials.Driver.main(Driver.java:31)
```

However, when I enter a polynomial without any negative numbers (ex: "3x^4+2x^3+1x^2+1x^1+8x^0"), there is no error. I believe the error is somehow coming from the Integer.parseInt(str2), but shouldn't it be able to parse a negative integer? This makes no sense at all to me, and I couldn't find anything anywhere else.. any help would be a great help. Thanks everyone!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a polynomial: ");

    String polynomial = userInput.nextLine();

    String newPoly = polynomial.replace("-", "+-").trim();

    String[] arr = newPoly.split("\\+");

    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);

        String str = arr[i].trim();
        String[] arr2 = str.split("x");

        String str2 = arr2[0];

        System.out.println(str2); //prints coefficient
        System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf('^')+1)); //prints exponent
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str2));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't parse expression to Integer. That's what error means

Comment: No the exception means that he's trying to parse an empty String.

Comment: Ohh yeah..!! I am wrong

Comment: But I don't think I have an empty string anywhere...

Comment: And it doesnt make sense that it works when there are no negative integers used in the polynomial

Comment: ohhhh... alright.. any tips to fix that??

Comment: Did you consider to validate and parse the input with an regexp matcher? Something like this could work: `(([+-]?\d+)x(^(\d+))?)+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your input string is `-3x^4+2x^3+1x^2-1x^1+8x^0` which will be converted into `+-3x^4+2x^3+1x^2-1x^1+8x^0` after following line.

```
String newPoly = polynomial.replace("-", "+-").trim();
```

So when you are trying to split it using `+` as a delimiter, First value will be generated as "" input string which is causing the exception.

Just add one if condition in for loop and you will be fine

```
for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].length()>0){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);

        String str = arr[i].trim();
        String[] arr2 = str.split("x");

        String str2 = arr2[0];

        System.out.println(str2); //prints coefficient
        System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf('^')+1)); //prints exponent
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str2));
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i get rid of this empty string while still maintaining this method of replacing and splitting?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pre-process like that. You can use a bit of intelligent regex for the `.split()` argument:

```
{

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a polynomial: ");

    String polynomial = userInput.nextLine();

    String[] arr = polynomial.split("\\+|(?=-)");

}
```

Then you would have to get rid of the empty string in the resulting `String[]`. Don't worry, you can modify the for loop, it's easier:

```
for (int i = ("".equals(arr[0]) ? 1 : 0); i < arr.length; i++)
```

This way the empty string in the first element of the array will be ignored, if it's there.

Comment: I solved my problem in my current code by just starting the loop at 1 instead of 0. I will definitely give your code a try as well. Thank you! @Unihedron

Comment: @Ybarra You're welcome. Please note that my main concern is that `polynomial.replace("-", "+-")` consumes unnecessary resources performing the regex replacement, which was not beneficial as you then break down the string (and throw away the effort). As `.split()` essentially does regex match and consumption, it would be better code.